# Use Boss RC 600 looper as a vocal multifx pedal?

Tags: guitar-effects, effects-pedal, looper-pedals

I'd like to use the Boss RC 600 looper mostly as a vocal multifx pedal with one track for my backing track. Is it possible to assign 6 different input fx to 6 separate footswitches?